# Using Relay/GraphQL with AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, relayjs, relay

I was wondering if someone could help me out on the following points:-

1. My aim here is to have a very cost effective architecture using Lambda along with the benefits of Relay to help with querying, caching, optimistic updates, etc. Is this architecture a good idea or am I overlooking something?
2. Are there any good examples of using Relay with Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using React + Relay/GraphQL: https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery

**React + Relay layer**: https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery/blob/master/frontend/src/app/AppRoutes.jsx

**GraphQL layer**: https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery/blob/master/schema/schema.js

I'm hosting this on my own server, sorry I can't really help you with using Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to use graphql on Lambda...successfuly :). I also created package to ease the setup pain. You can use it or just inspire how it could be done: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-graphql